# Retrieve tags from a file in AWS S3 with Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, filesystems, storage

I am trying to retrieve the `Tags` property of a file from AWS S3 with Laravel 5.8 (for Tags in AWS, I mean this)
[image]
I know that I can retrieve a file like:

```
$storage->get($filePath);
```

But how to get the tags from that file?

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have to use getObjectTagging api of aws

```
$result = $client->getObjectTagging([
    'Bucket' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
    'Key' => '<string>', // REQUIRED
    'VersionId' => '<string>',
]);
```

For Example

```
$result = $client->getObjectTagging([
    'Bucket' => 'examplebucket',
    'Key' => 'HappyFace.jpg',
]);
```

Comment: Awesome, this works for me. Just for future references, just clarifying that `$client` is an instance of `S3Client`.